# How to invert a random walk

Tags: optimization, references, monte-carlo, random-walk

I have a random walk dynamic parameterized in a function let's say $f(x)$ e given a $x_0$ I can retrieve a curve of this initial value after several simulations. But I need to "invert" this random walk in the sense that given a interval $I=[a,b]$ I need to find the best range or values that the most of their end points lie on $I$.

Is there any methods or algorithms to further research?